# Update Spark dataframe to populate data from another dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes. I want to take distinct values of 1 column and link it with all the rows of another dataframe. For e.g -

Dataframe 1 : df1 contains

```
scenarioId
---------------
 101
 102
 103
```

Dataframe 2 : df2 contains columns

```
trades
-------------------------------------
isin price 
ax11 111
re32 909
erre 445
```

Expected output

```
trades
----------------
isin price scenarioid
ax11 111   101
re32 909   101
erre 445   101
ax11 111   102
re32 909   102
erre 445   102
ax11 111   103
re32 909   103
erre 445   103
```

Note that i dont have a possibility to join the 2 dataframes on a common column. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `cross join` or cartessian product:

```
val result = df1.crossJoin(df2)
```

although I do not recommend it as the amount of data rises very fast. You'll get all possible pairs - elements of cartessian product (the number will be number of rows in `df1` times number of rows in `df2`).